# Gradle unable to resolve dependency

Tags: android, pubnub

I am trying to develop an Android app using Pubnub's realtime API facilities. As per the documentation we need to add a gradle dependency line below within the **build.gradle** file:

```
compile 'com.pubnub:pubnub:4.1.0'
```

Strangely enough, Gradle is not able to satisfy this dependency. My repository configuration within the Gradle build script is as follows:

```
repositories {
        jcenter()

    }
```

I tried adding `mavenCentral()` instead of `jcenter()` but still no luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Please note: I am adding only the relevant sections of the **build.gradle** file since I do not have the authority to paste the whole build script.

Also, this is my first time with the Android ecosystem - hence any help in pointing out obvious newbie errors would be great.

Comment: `jcenter()` is a superset of `mavenCentral()`, so using `jcenter()` is fine. Make sure you are adding the dependency to the app build.gradle and not your root build.gradle file. The dependency resolved for me.

Comment: That's not the latest version, by the way. https://www.pubnub.com/docs/java/pubnub-java-sdk-v4

Comment: Agreed, the dependency resolves here. If you are comfortable doing a command-line build, try adding the `--refresh-dependencies` switch to some task (e.g., `./gradlew --refresh-dependencies assembleDebug`). Sometimes, if there is an initial hiccup with resolving a dependency, Gradle will not try again to fix the problem for 24 hours. `--refresh-dependencies` forces it to try to resolve the dependency again immediately. Unfortunately, I don't know how to trigger this from the IDE.

Comment: @JaredRummler Thanks for the update. In my Android studio project i see only a module level build.gradle file. This is the file that contains the dependency.

Comment: @cricket_007 It really does not matter which version I use.  I tried with the link you provided and yet  Gradle does not seem to resolve that dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Did you right click on app, go to Open module settings, click on the Dependencies tab, click on the +, choose add module dependency and then ok?

Comment: That did not help. I can see all the dependencies added within the Gradle file listed as Maven dependencies within the Dependencies dialog